# The usage of 'get to ~ing'

Tags: usage

'get to' means 'have to' or 'have got to'. And I learned that after 'get to', there should be infinitive, but I saw a sentence which is showing 'get to + ~ing' form, so I don't know how to translate it.

Here is the example. (from 'Baker's blue-jay yarn' by Mark Twain)

I've noticed a good deal, and there's no bird, or cow, or anything that uses as good grammar as a blue-jay. You may say a cat uses good grammar. Well, a cat does - but you let a cat get excited once; you let a cat ***get to pulling*** fur with another cat on a shed, nights, and you'll hear grammar that will give you the lockjaw.

Comment: Bear in mind the cited passage is well over a century old (and it was always "folksy dialect" anyway). This figurative use of *get to X = reach a point where X occurs* is probably *always* "informal", but it's still current. It's totally separate from the *[to have] **got** to* usage implying *obligation*.

Answer (score 1):

Two different meanings of "get to".

**We get to see each other only on the weekends.**

*Circumstances allow us* to see each other only on the weekends.

**Cats get to pulling fur....**

Cats *begin to* pull fur (i.e. fight) with each other.

"Got to" (not 'get to') means  must, to have to.

**I've got to take my suit to the cleaners.**